# Stop image resize on page zoom in and out

Tags: css

Is there a way to stop image from zooming in and out when you zoom the page in and out using CSS?

To make the image to stay full no matter how zoomed is the browser.

Comment: It would be more helpful to tell us more about the context and how you would like this to be achieve. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyhow, I don't see how you could bypass this browser feature with css. In js, maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Just putting `width: 100%;` should do the trick.

If this does not solve your problem, you just have to find the container that causes the problem and place the same css on that container too.